# How to find inter-country buses in Europe?

Tags: europe, buses

I was traveling from Zurich to Frankfurt, and when I asked a tourist information, the guy advised that the best way is train. I took the train, and when arrived in Frankfurt, I found that there is a German company having bus from Zurich to Frankfurt with 1/3 of the train price.

The problem is that bus companies are small and not-connected. On the other hand, such small companies have website mainly in their local languages (not English). As a result, it is difficult for a foreigner to find the best option for bus from a country to another; particularly, as they operate from small stations rather than a big united terminal (as one can go and ask for options).

Are there resources (e.g., websites) for searching all bus routes around Europe?

Comment: Google comes to mind. Rome2Rio.

Comment: @Karlson not a perfect solution! websites are not in English, and Google shows the results based on keywords rather than services.

Comment: Searching for "Zurich Frankfurt bus" isn't language specific and in addition Google while using keywords doesn't produce result only based on keywords.

Comment: I agree the buses are useful for saving a lot of money. I would, however, also with respect to future readers, like to add that while a long distance bus can easily be 1/3 or less of the train price, bridging the same distance can also easily be 3 times or more of the train ride duration. (Not saying that is definitely the case for the trip between Zürich and Frankfurt, it's just something to consider.)

Comment: If you are interested in the cheapest mean of transport, you should even consider flying. In Europe, flying with a low-cost airline is often cheaper than going by train.

Answer (score 8):

In many countries, there are only one or two companies offering long-distance buses and Eurolines would be the only one with a regular network of international buses. So the first things to check is the national transport company and Eurolines.

But there are more and more alternatives and in my experience it seems especially true for Germany. I don't know how comprehensive their coverage is but [Rome2rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/) does include several of them and has two different solutions [for this particular journey](http://www.rome2rio.com/de/s/Zurich/Frankfurt).

Answer (score 3):

[Busbud](http://www.busbud.com) is quickly becoming the go to site for bus tickets around the world, as it's adding more inventory to its database. Currently there are many routes in Europe that you can search, compare and book bus tickets directly on the busbud site, otherwise you can view schedules and prices and get redirected to the bus companies website to purchase your ticket.

Very soon, there will be some new bus routes added for Spain and Turkey as well as some other countries around Europe and the world.

Also another thing to keep in mind is that there is no additional fees for booking on busbud, the price you will pay is the same as on the website of the bus company.

Comment: The last two paragraphs sound like promotional material, are you affiliated with busbud? It's OK as long as the answer is valuable but you should disclose any affiliation.