# Travelling from Leipzig to Strasbourg

Tags: france, germany, routes

I am planning to travel to Strasbourg, France from Leipzig, Germany. I haven't found any routes without a huge number of stopovers enroute. I  am open to traveling by bus, train or flight as long as it cheap(ish) I am also ok with the Berlin-Strasbourg route, if there is one.

Can anyone suggest a travel plan  for this?

Comment: The best I see now is via the DB Bahn site, via Frankfurt and from there on the TGV to Strasbourg. The savings rate on this is about 80 euros. Is this the best I could expect?

Comment: @pnuts which is the bus and where to book it?

Comment: go through belgium, it's like, totally much easier.

Comment: @easymoden00b Is this a joke?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The train solution you found sounds reasonable to me. The connections between Strasbourg and Germany never were very good. There used to be slow international trains to Munich and further to Vienna and there are now some TGV but the high-speed rail network does not extend all the way to Strasbourg yet and the fastest trains to France run further north, from Frankfurt over Saarbrücken and Mannheim to Paris without stopping elsewhere in France.

The price also sounds about right for this distance in Germany, as train travel is relatively expensive there. Still, there are two ways to pay less than that:

- The *Schönes Wochenende* or *Quer-durchs-Land* tickets cost EUR 44 and allow you to travel all day *but only on regional trains*, which means even more stopovers and longer travel times.
- Since your final destination is outside Germany, the journey qualifies for an *Europa-Spezial-Ticket*, which means the cheapest fare is EUR 39. However, you have to be flexible and book long in advance to get it. On bahn.de, you can use the *[Sparpreis-Finder](http://ps.bahn.de/preissuche/preissuche/psc_start.post?)* to look for them more easily than using the regular search function.

As for other transportation modes, flying is unlikely to be attractive but buses might be cheaper than the train. [Rome2rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/de/s/Leipzig/Strasbourg) is very useful for these kinds of comparisons. You can also find more info on bus travel in Germany in previous questions:

- [Searching for internal bus connections in Germany](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34046/searching-for-internal-bus-connections-in-germany)
- [Cheap bus lines in Germany, something like Orangeways?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8458/cheap-bus-lines-in-germany-something-like-orangeways)
- [How to find inter-country buses in Europe?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/33896/how-to-find-inter-country-buses-in-europe/33952)
- [Traveling from Paris to Düsseldorf](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38606/traveling-from-paris-to-dusseldorf)

Finally, another option is ride sharing, which is quite popular in Germany (you have to look for “Mitfahrgelegenheit”).